# Я обновил Telerik Angular до 14 версии, перестали отображаться иконки

Tags: angular, kendo, telerik

Обновил Telerik до 14 версии.

После этого иконки не показываются, хотя svg-иконки отображаются.
В чем может быть проблема?
До этого все работало.
Может что-то с шрифтом или лицензией, которой у меня нет?

Стили .к-i-... отсутствуют во вкладке браузера "Elements".

```html
<button (click)="refresh()">
  <kendo-icon name="refresh"/>
</button>
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.8",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.8.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngrx/eslint-plugin": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^14.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-fluent": "^7.0.1",
```

angular.ts

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-fluent/dist/all.css"
  },
  "src/styles.less",
  "src/kendo.less",
  "src/assets/fonts/OpenSans/open-sans.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того, как все пакеты были обновлены с помощью ncu, я восстановил предыдущую версию темы в package.json.

Теперь работает.